# jboss 4 JNDI resource of type java.util.Properties

Tags: java, jboss

I'm working on a project, that has to run on JBoss 4.2.3 and I need to have a .properties file as an external resource. I found a short description on how to do that with JBossAS 7 - [custom JNDI resource of type java.util.Properties](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241892)
But this tutorial uses a configuration file \configuration\standalone.xml, and this file does not exists in my jboss AS 4.2.3. Looking for any advice here, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jboss 4.2.3 supports deploying a properties object to jndi.  todo so, you use the jndi binding service manger. you create a XX-service.xml file and put that in your deploy folder.  an example jndi-service.xml is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE server PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD MBean Service 4.0//EN"
          "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-service_4_0.dtd">
<server>
   <mbean code="org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr"
         name="jboss.tests:service=JNDIBindingServiceMgr">
      <attribute name="BindingsConfig" serialDataType="jbxb">
         <jndi:bindings
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"
            xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0 resource:jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd"
            >
            <jndi:binding name="urls/jboss-home">
               <jndi:value type="java.net.URL">http://www.jboss.org</jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>

            <jndi:binding name="hosts/localhost">
               <jndi:value editor="org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.InetAddressEditor">
                  127.0.0.1
               </jndi:value>
            </jndi:binding>

            <jndi:binding name="maps/testProps">
               <java:properties xmlns:java="urn:jboss:java-properties"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xs:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:java-properties resource:java-properties_1_0.xsd">
                  <java:property>
                     <java:key>key1</java:key>
                     <java:value>value1</java:value>
                  </java:property>
                  <java:property>
                     <java:key>key2</java:key>
                     <java:value>value2</java:value>
                  </java:property>
               </java:properties>               
            </jndi:binding>
         </jndi:bindings>
      </attribute>
      <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
   </mbean>

</server>
```

see also

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JNDIBindingServiceMgr